# Creating an autospec'd mock with a name value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to use `mock.create_autospec` to create an autospecc'd mock with a `name` kwarg. However, I get a `TypeError` exception whenever I set the `name` kwarg.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import mock
>>> def a():
...  print "blah"
... 
>>> a()
blah
>>> q = mock.create_autospec(a)
>>> q
<function a at 0x7f184ceb1938>
>>> q()
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139742347069904'>
```

`mock()` isn't a very descriptive name for a `MagicMock` object, so I try to set a value for `name`:

```
>>> q = mock.create_autospec(a, name="a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 2186, in create_autospec
    name=_name, **_kwargs)
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

Why does this happen? When I try to make a regular `MagicMock`, things go fine:

```
>>> q = mock.MagicMock(name="a")
>>> q
<MagicMock name='a' id='139742346475088'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a conflict of provided and generated names. Probably it's a bug, so you should try reporting it.

There is another way to create an autospec'd mock with meaningful name, but it requires patching:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.a', autospec=True):
    print(repr(a()))

# <MagicMock name='a()' id='140705539482000'>
```

Comment: That seems unnecessarily roundabout. I've submitted a bug report to their tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=224&thanks=224&ts=1396916083